# Unix: bash script calling script, and relative paths

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, docker

I have the following directory structure

```
.
|_build.sh
|_dir
  |_build.sh
  |_Dockerfile
```

Here is the content of upper level build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./dir/build.sh
```

and here is the content of bottom level build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t test .
```

However, when I run upper level build.sh I get the following error

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFi
leAttributesEx C:\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the fil
e specified.
```

How do I preserve the relative path relative to the location of the script being called?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach but might work. This in your top level build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./dir
docker build -t test .
```